# Plotting only a maximum value of domain

Tags: plotting

I made a table containing many lists of c and Tpop function value. Since the domain is duplicated in the table, I have an image as below when I plot it (y-axis = TPop, x-axis = c). I want to plot only the maximum of the Tpop value based on c domain.

Could anyone help me how to implement this? Thanks in advance.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{c, 
   TPop[x, 11.35, 5.2, 100, 0.1, 53, 0.1, 1, c, 10, 0, 0]}, {x, 0, 
   2}, {c, 0, 1000, 0.1}], Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: does `ListLinePlot[ Table[{c,   Max[Table[ TPop[x, 11.35, 5.2, 100, 0.1, 53, 0.1, 1, c, 10, 0, 0], {x, 0,  2}]]}, {c, 0, 1000, 0.1}], Mesh -> All]` give what you need?

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: What is `TPop`?